# How can I display a pygooglechart in a Django view?

Tags: python, django, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I'm currently playing around with [pygooglechart](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/).
It's a python wrapper for Google charts.

In my views.py I have the following:

```
from pygooglechart import PieChart3D

def pytest(request):
     chart = PieChart3D(250, 100)
     chart.add_data([20, 10])
     chart.set_pie_labels(['Hello', 'World'])
```

In my urls.py I have linked up the view:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    (r'^report/$', 'App.djangoapp.views.reporting'),
    (r'^facebook/', 'App.djangoapp.views.facebook'),
    (r'^twitter/', 'App.djangoapp.views.twitter'),
    (r'^pytest/', 'App.djangoapp.views.pytest'),
```

I know I need to put in a HttpResponse for my pytest view but I don't know how to render the image for the client who is accessing that url. When the client accesses that url, it should just generate an image of the graph. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You know the [google charts image api](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) was deprecated in april 2012 and will cease to function in april 2015 right? You might want to save some trouble and compatibility issues in the future and find an alternative now while you are still developing...

Comment: @Ngenator you are absolutely right! hmm do you know of any other way I can still render charts through Google's new charts api? I think Google is moving away from the images so that the charts can become more interactive...is there anyway I can render it in a template just like the solution below?

Comment: If you are looking to use image charts, you can see if something like [pychart](http://home.gna.org/pychart/) will work with your project, or you can always use google's normal chart api with their [python wrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gviz_api_lib). Another alternative that I have used before is [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

Comment: @Ngenator thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use few approaches.

**Example use redirect:**

*views.py*

> ```
> from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
> from pygooglechart import PieChart3D
>
>
> def pytest(request):
>     chart = PieChart3D(250, 100)
>     chart.add_data([20, 10])
>     chart.set_pie_labels(['Hello', 'World'])
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(chart.get_url())
> ```

**Example use with template:**

*views.py*

> ```
> from django.template import RequestContext
> from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
> from pygooglechart import PieChart3D
>
>
> def pytest(request):
>     chart = PieChart3D(250, 100)
>     chart.add_data([20, 10])
>     chart.set_pie_labels(['Hello', 'World'])
>     context = RequestContext(request, {
>         'url_to_chart': chart.get_url()
>     })
>     template = 'path/to/template.html'
>     return render_to_response(template, context)
> ```

*template.html*

> ```
> <img src="{{ url_to_chart }}" alt="" />
> ```

[image]